# DRY use of multiple fields of an Option's value

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

**Background**

I'm using a java web UI library (Vaadin, but that's irrelevant - I'm not using the Scaladin add-on) which has a `TextField` that has a method `setValue(String)` to set the current text value.

As it's a java library, it has no notion of `Option` but can represent a `null` value as e.g. an empty string (it's configurable).  So I've written an implicit wrapper class as follows:

```
implicit class ExtendedTextField(self: TextField) {
    def :=(value: String) = self.setValue(value)
    def :=(maybeValue: Option[String]) = self.setValue(maybeValue.orNull)
}
```

This allows me to set the value using the `:=` operator directly on a TextField instance and allows me to deal with the Option to null conversion in a single place.

**Problem**

When I have e.g. a form with a bunch of text fields showing the values for some object of type X, then if I have an Option[X] I'm doing this:

```
fieldA := (for (x <- maybeX) yield x.valueA)
fieldB := (for (x <- maybeX) yield x.valueB)
fieldC := (for (x <- maybeX) yield x.valueC)
...
```

In other words, I want to call the `:=` with Some(string) in case I have maybeX is Some but with None if maybeX is none.  In addition, suppose x.valueD is actually an Option[String], I would call

```
fieldD := (for (x <- maybeX) yield x.valueD).flatten
```

(I could simply always call `flatten`, but it wouldn't have an effect if there are no nested options)

Is there a nicer way to write this, getting rid of all the duplicate for comprehensions and flattening the result?  Maybe using a macro?

I'd prefer not to use reflection (I'm sure it will be possible to put all the fields in a sequence, zip it with a sequence containing the property names, then map this using a function that returns None or does the relflection lookup, and also flattens the result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is about as compact as it gets since it is a set of different map transforms you want to perform if it has got a value. You might get it a bit shorter with `map` instead of a for comprehension:

```
fieldA := x.map(_.valueA)
fieldB := x.map(_.valueB)
fieldC := x.map(_.valueC)
```

and for you case of an option inside of x `flatMap` which gets you the same result as map + flatten:

```
fieldD := x.flatMap(_.valueD)
```

You might be able to create a macro that does this but you will then trade of this repetition against how hard your code will be to understand, and the gain will probably be very little.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about defining := operators for Tuple2, Tuple3 etc. but I guess if I can import x._ there's not much point in trying to make it any shorter than `fieldA := map(_.valueA)`.  Thanks for the suggestion to use map / flatMap!